# TypeError: Can't convert 'QRadioButton' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, typeerror

Im doing a quiz and when the person gets a question wrong i want to tell them theyve got it wrong and what was the right answer. Im getting my questions from a database and setting the text each time the next button is pressed

```
print("You chose the incorrect answer the correct answer was" + (self.Correctanswer))
```

However this returns the error

```
print("You chose the incorrect answer the correct answer was" + (self.Correctanswer))
TypeError: Can't convert 'QRadioButton' object to str implicitly
```

i done some research and i saw this method

```
 print("You chose the incorrect answer the correct answer was" + format(self.Correctanswer))
```

Even though this removed the error it didnt display the correct answer

```
You chose the incorrect answer the correct answer was<PyQt4.QtGui.QRadioButton object at 0x0000000003EB4F78>
```

The question is how can i make it display the correct answer currently in the radiobutton. the way i set the radio buttons is like this

```
self.Correctanswer.setText(self.Questions[0][2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Radio Button is an Object. That's told by the output `<PyQt4.QtGui.QRadioButton object at 0x0000000003EB4F78>`.

Just as you use `self.Correctanswer.setText()`, to set its displayed text, you have tu use a similar method to receive the text from such an object. Look at the PyQt4 docs for the corresponding function, but i guess something like `self.Correctanswer.getText()` will work. It's usually `.setText()` and `.getText()`, or `.setValue()` and `.getValue()`, or something like this :-)

Comment: thanks for your comment, how would you code it it in the terms of a print statement? like this; print "("You chose the incorrect answer the correct answer was" + (self.Correctanswer.getText()))"? (this doesnt work)

Comment: `print "("You chose the incorrect answer the correct answer was" + (self.Correctanswer.getText()))` couldn't work - look at the brackets and quotes. I don't use/know Qt4 and i couldn't find the corresponding documentation after a short websearch, so i can't provide a tested and working example. But why don't you try to get a value from your radiobutton, first? Then you can add it to an existing string. Just try to print the value itself, like: `print self.Correctanswer.getText()` and continue from there. Keep your error checking as simple as possible.

Comment: @xph. Qt doesn't generally use the "get" prefix: so it's just `text()` and `setText()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Personally, i think this could be a little confusing - *set* or *get* really make clear what is going on. But that's just me - thanks for providing the needed method!

Comment: @ekhumoro and xph it works. Just had to put ".text" on it thanks for both your help